# Txt file as config file

Tags: c#, configuration

I found application that use .txt files as config files.

The Files looks like

[[plugin.save]]=[[Save]]

how do I use it in C#?

how can I read The file to my application to use Values in [] as config?

Comment: Probably just create some sort of config class at the start of your application, fill it by parsing with regex. Then make it accessable to where you need it (probably using some static class)

Comment: how i read it with regex expression?

Comment: Look into regex on google, there's tons of tutorials on it. Then search the web on how to parse text from files using regex, and you're done!

Comment: Seeing the format, it reminds me of an Ini file. This link could be a tarter : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to read it as a regular file. Reading it use Dictionary to store values.
Example code:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> configuration = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        Regex r = new Regex(@"\[\[(\w+)\]\]=\[\[(\w+)\]\]");

        string[] configArray = {"[[param1]]=[[Value1]]", "[[param2]]=[[Value2]]"};// File.ReadAllLines("some.txt");

        foreach (string config in configArray)
        {
             Match m = r.Match(config);
            configuration.Add(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
```

Please note to check for possible null values.
Note also that regex expression should be different if config values can contain for example spaces.

Comment: sorry? i am using regular file reading

but how do i use Dictonary to use it?
static Dictionary<string, string> Language = new Dictionary<string, string>();


 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@".\" + Langua))
                   {
                       string line;
                       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
var config = File.ReadAllLines(FileLocation)
```

And then parse it with the

```
String.Split()
```

Might use regex as well.

Comment: ty for the suggest but still regex it more easy
i know how to use regex easily but i dont think it was write to use regex. so i ask if someone know other way

Comment: Regex is clearly overkill, splitting lines on the `=` character seems the most practical way